# Clothes size calculator in js

Tags: javascript

I am now doing a clothes size calculator widget in js, now it checks for the values in the inputs using this

```
var sizes= [];
//Array containing example sizes
sizes[0] = ["XS", "1", "2", "4"];
sizes[1] = ["S", "6", "7", "9"];
sizes[2] = ["M", "11", "13", "15"];
sizes[3] = ["L", "17", "19", "22"];
sizes[4] = ["XL", "24", "27", "28"];
sizes[5] = ["XXL", "30", "32", "34"];
//In this function I receive values for the length, width and sleeve length from an HTML form and compare whether they are smaller than the clothes size
function rightSize(lon, alt, sleeve){
  console.clear();

  for (i=0; i < sizes.length; i++) {
    var rightLon = lon < sizes[i][1];
    var rightAlt = alt < sizes[i][1];
    var rightSleeve = sleeve < sizes[i][1];

    console.log("iteration: " + i +  rightLon);
    console.log("iteration: " + i +  rightAlt);
    console.log("iteration: " + i +  rightSleeve);
    if(rightLon  && rightAlt && rightSleeve ){
        alert("Size: " + sizes[i][0]);
       break;
    }
  }
}
```

But when I call it with almost every value it returns S as the correct value.

EDIT: Here's the HTML form-

```
<input type="number" name="largo" id="lon">
<input type="number" name="alto" id="alt">
<input type="number" name="ancho" id="sleeve">
<INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="button" Value="Click"onClick="rightSize(document.getElementById('lon').value, document.getElementById('alt').value, document.getElementById('sleeve').value)">
```

Comment: Please explain what exactly your code is doing, it will help people understand and help you better.

Comment: Added comments to code. Please let me know if further clarification is needed

Answer (score 0):

I think you just made a typo in the `rightSize()` function. Your old code had rightLon, rightAlt, and rightSleeve all using `sizes[i][1]`

EDIT: Also, you had `for(i=0;i<talles.length;i++)` instead of `for(var i =0;`

```
var sizes= [];
//Array containing example sizes
sizes[0] = ["XS", "1", "2", "4"];
sizes[1] = ["S", "6", "7", "9"];
sizes[2] = ["M", "11", "13", "15"];
sizes[3] = ["L", "17", "19", "22"];
sizes[4] = ["XL", "24", "27", "28"];
sizes[5] = ["XXL", "30", "32", "34"];
//In this function I receive values for the length, width and sleeve length from an HTML form and compare whether they are smaller than the     clothes size
function rightSize(lon, alt, sleeve){
  console.clear();

  for (var i=0; i < talles.length; i++) {
    var rightLon = lon < sizes[i][1];
    var rightAlt = alt < sizes[i][2];
    var rightSleeve = sleeve < sizes[i][3];

    console.log("iteration: " + i +  rightLon);
    console.log("iteration: " + i +  rightAlt);
    console.log("iteration: " + i +  rightSleeve);
  }
}
```

Please tell me in the comments if this still doesn't work.

Comment: It definitely improved, as in, now it is actually comparing the right things. I've now set this inside the for

      if(rightLon && rightAlt && rightSleeve ){
           alert("Size: " + sizes[i][0]);
           break;
       }

but it still returns S even for really big values

Comment: Okay, is it fixed then, or do you need anything else?

Comment: @js_student-92 Alright, please see the updated code above.

Comment: It still returns size S no matter what values I input

Answer (score 0):

Spent a day and a half trying to figure it out. It was the "". I was comparing numbers to strings.